# How do I get error stack trace information for custom module

Tags: error, debugging, developer-log

I am writing an module for EE 3 and when I am displaying data from a search I am getting this error but I am having trouble tracking down the root cause since it is not displaying an trace information and there does not seem to be an details in the apache log files, How do I go about about getting full trace information for this error?

```
Warning

htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Addons/Addons.php, line 72
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that in one of my views I had all the form input names in an array called 'search'.  This ended up conflicting with the expression engine admin search form field name 'search' that expected 'search' to be a string and not an array like I created.  I renamed my array to 'module_search' and that eliminated the error.